# Can a paladin's Divine Sense detect if an object is cursed?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin, curses

We ran in to this situation recently. The paladin of the group claimed that his Divine Sense can detect if an object is cursed or not. Is that really the case?

I found that a bit overpowered, but we try to keep to RAW as closely as possible.

Comment: Related: [Can a character detect that an item is cursed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68313/can-a-character-detect-that-an-item-is-cursed); more loosely related: [What is the purpose of the Identify spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114744/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-identify-spell)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### No, RAW it cannot detect that.

The text of the paladin's [Divine Sense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#DivineSense) feature reads:

> Until the end of your next turn, you **know the location of any celestial, fiend, or undead** within 60 feet of you that is not behind total cover.

It continues:

> Within the same radius, you also detect the presence of any place or object that has been **consecrated** or **desecrated**, as with the *hallow* spell.

So there is **nothing about sensing cursed objects**. Moreover, let's look at an actual cursed object in the DMG. For example, the [*armor of vulnerability*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/armor-of-vulnerability) states explicitly:

> This armor is cursed, a fact that is revealed **only when an *identify* spell is cast on the armor or you attune to it**.

This doesn't mean there cannot be an ability or item that would recognize a curse in such an object, but the paladin's Divine Sense is not it.

Comment: So if there is a curse that also gives "desecrated" to item, then and only then Paladin can detect it - but even then, he will detect desecrated quality, not the curse that caused it, right?

Comment: @Mołot Yes, that's how I see it